# Como importar classes a partir de suas subclasses em PHP?

Tags: php, classes, importação

Basicamente, possuo 3 arquivos localizados em diretórios diferentes:

```
diretorio_do_projeto/classes/config.php
diretorio_do_projeto/classes/abstract/abstract-dao.php
diretorio_do_projeto/classes/dao/modelo-dao.php
```

O arquivo `config.php` define as constantes para acesso ao banco de dados, e é incluído no arquivo `abstract-dao.php`, que por sua vez é incluído no arquivo `modelo-dao.php`.

O problema ocorre quando incluo o arquivo `modelo-dao.php` em alguma página que não está num subdiretório de `/classes`, o arquivo `abstract-dao.php` não é encontrado.

Existe uma forma diferente de importar uma classe que não seja através dos comandos `require` ou `include`?

As únicas soluções que consegui pensar foram de retirar as importações nas classes e importa-las uma a uma na página em que as utilizarei, ou deixa-las no mesmo diretório da página.

Comment: Já pesquisou algo sobre autoloads (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php) e namespaces (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer isso usando namespaces.

Seria muito semelhante à utilização de packages e imports do Java.

```
namespace Projeto\Dao;

class Pessoa {
}
```

Seria relativo ao seguinte, em Java:

```
package projeto.dao;

public class Pessoa {
}
```

E para usar as classes criadas:

```
use Projeto\Dao\Pessoa;
$pessoa = new Pessoa();
```

Em Java:

```
import projeto.dao;
// ... public class, variaveis e etc.
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
```

O problema é que isso não funciona por mágica e você precisa configurar o autoload do PHP para saber onde buscar as classes (saber em quais pastas buscar).
Recomendo a lida sobre padrões de autoload (PSR-0).

Esse artigo em português explica bem o uso de namespace:
http://www.diogomatheus.com.br/blog/php/entendendo-namespaces-no-php/

**Edit**

O Tuyoshi Vinicius deixou uma nota muito importante: isso só esta disponível a partir da versão 5.3 do PHP.

Comment: Obrigado cara, a analogia com Java ajudou muito =)

Answer (score 0):

A unica forma de carregar arquivos que contem as classes em php é com `include`, `require` e etc.. você pode utilizar o padrão `PSR-0` que define como os arquivos serão carregados a partir de um autoloader. Você pode encontrar uma boa explicação [aqui](http://php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)

uma saida rapida para o seu problema é carregar as classes pelo `path` completo, exemplo:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/diretorio_do_projeto/classes/abstract/abstract-dao.php');
```

mas ainda sim eu recomendo o uso do padrão PSR-0, muitos frameworks como [laravel](http://laravel.com) ja utilizam este padrão.

NOTA:
Só é possível utilizar o padrão PSR-0 a partir da versão PHP 5.3 que da suporte a namespace

Comment: Para novos projetos, é muito mais interessante a adoção do PSR-4 ao invés do PSR-0.

Comment: Outro detalhe: PSR-0 tem um adaptação que possibilita sua implementação em versões anteriores do php 5.3 (`_` como separador de diretórios). O que só é suportado a partir do 5.3 é `namespace`. http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

Answer (score 0):

O melhor mecanismo será mediante um mecanismo de autoload do tipo:

```
function autoload($class) {
    if (file_exists(LIBS_PATH . $class . ".php")) {
        require LIBS_PATH . $class . ".php";
    } else {
        exit ('A classe ' . $class . '.php em falta.');
    }
}
spl_autoload_register("autoload");
```

Neste caso LIBS_PATH é definida com "define" e deverá ser a raiz do diretório onde estarão incluídos todas as bibliotecas a usar. Como colocado na pergunta... É pretendido um conjunto de sub directórios que pode ser incluído com um algoritmo para pesquisar todos os sub directórios antes do require.

Desta forma forma basta utilizar as classes sem realizar "includes" ou "requires" a não ser a do próprio autoloader.

spl_autoload_register utiliza uma cache que é muito útil em termos de performance em casos de se utilizar uma classe mais do que uma vez... Entre outras características.

Answer (score 0):

Para importar uma classe sem utilizar o require ou include é recomendado que utilize o PSR-0 ([Link](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)) um padrão que muitos aderiram (Mesmo sendo discutida para se usar o PSR-4 em vez do PSR-0). Ele pode ser facilmente configurado utilizando o composer. Um link para facilitar sua configuração: [Link](http://iagoeffting.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/utilizando-o-autoloader-do-composer/)

Existem outras formas, como colocar direto no arquivo composer.json, mas já que você não utiliza, acho que esse é o jeito mais fácil.